# Restricting input to 1s and 0s

Tags: java, regex, javafx

Im working with JavaFx and I need to create a FieldInput that takes in a singular 1 or 0. I have managed to remove the alphabet and keep the string len to 1.

For some reason I Cant crack numbers

```
public static void addTextLimiter(final TextField textField, final int maxLength) {
    textField.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(final ObservableValue<? extends String> ov, final String oldValue, final String newValue) {
            if (textField.getText().length() > maxLength) {
                String s = textField.getText().substring(0, maxLength);
                textField.setText(s);
            }

            if (!newValue.matches("\\d{0,7}([\\.]\\d{0,4})?")) {
                    textField.setText(oldValue);
            }

        } 
    });
}
```

Comment: newValue.matches("\\d{0,7}([\\.]\\d{0,4})?" is checking for any - to 7 digits folllowed by an optional ( '.'  and 0 to 4 more digits)  - check instead of the vaue is "0" or "1"

Comment: plain wrong approach (for several reasons) use a TextFormatter

Answer (score 1):

Your current regex matches 0-7 digits optionally followed by a decimal point and 0-4 more digits.

To match a single digit, `0` or `1`, use square brackets to "match a single character from the set" `[01]`.

Answer (score -1):

This regex gonna work, it onlys accept one single character and you can only choose 0 or 1. `^[01]{1}$`.